# I have the following usecase and looking for the right solution

Tags: php, css, html, seo

Hi friends i need a solution for Bad value 100% for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit but saw % instead. for this

```
<div class="item">
    <img alt="" src="http://web4cinema.com/img/MainBannerImageDir/146494909736kabali-new-banner-web4cinema.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use `style="width: 100%"` in your html but will just make your css a mess after.

**try do this on your css file:**

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

**or**

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

so like that you don't need insert `style="width: 100%"` in all your img html tags

if you wanna use just width, you should insert just px values or numbers.

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```